# Uploading a file using HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html

I am using PHP to handle a form and upload a file. Everything works great from my localhost but when it is live, some files won't upload. I am not getting any errors and the php.ini settings are set to the right settings. What could I be doing wrong?

My PHP:

```
$target2= UPLOADPATH . $cover_photo;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cover-pic-input']['tmp_name'], $target2);
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us any code. Can you show us the way that the code is being uploaded?

Comment: It could be almost anything.  Show some code.

Comment: Is is a permission issue?

Comment: There are no permission issues. I can upload other files.

Comment: What kinds of files upload and what kinds don't upload?

Comment: @Arian [move_uploaded_file](http://us2.php.net/move_uploaded_file) is a built-in PHP function.  It takes the temp file and saves it into a directory you specify.

Comment: Are you checking for errors in the `$_FILES` array?  Try `if ($_FILES["cover-pic-input"]["error"] > 0) echo $_FILES["cover-pic-input"]["error"];`